# Inserting data, locally, before posting to a remote form

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form (`remote_form.php`) on remote servers that post to a script that I have sitting on a webserver. This script receives the remote data and processes it into our database.

Currently, my `<form>` tag looks like this:

`<form name='cform' action="https://mysite/incoming/data_listener.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateFrm(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

On each one of my remote servers has it's own SQL Server instance with data that my form uses for prefilling purposes. What I'd like to do is before my data posts to my `data_listener.php` script, I'd like to make an insert into the local database.

Besides submitting the to the `remote_form.php` itself, doing the local insert, then redirecting to the `data_listener.php` with `$_GET` variables (this would involve editing `data_listener` to handle `$_GET` in addition to `$_POST`), do I have other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd stick with your call to the remote_form.php. Do your local insert then you could use a context_stream_create() and file_get_contents() - to spoof a POST to your data_listener.php rather than your GET (I assume using  header("Location: ....")  or jumping out to a javascript window.location(...) ).

See the example at the php manual page:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Cheers.